# RDP Connection after entering credentials very slow to connect, then fast again after connecting

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I've been using remote desktop in the past with no issues, It's been a year since I used it, today I decided to connect using it but it's super slow (minutes) trying to connect.   It's fast to ask for the credentials, then hangs for a long time, once connected it's fast again.

The remote allowed any version of remote desktop, I did a test where I could connect without using NLA (Network Level Authentication) and it was fast, no delay and was able to login though the GUI.

This last attempt closing the RDP (connected using NLA) seemed to have the disconnect hanging as well (caused windows explorer to hang (desktop, other apps)).  Until I ended the rdp task (and after about 10 seconds things started to respond again).

Win10X64 Pro.

I've tried connecting to different targets on the network, all the same.

Any idea on what could have happened to cause this or how to fix?

Comment: Well in this case rebooting everything seem to have solved whatever was throwing it off.

Comment: But it's only temporary, eventually it comes back to 4 minutes to connect or do anything with NLA.  Not only that, it can also hang the entire windows UI until it clear, not all the time, but sometimes it ends up where you can't click on start menu, taskbar items, etc..  You can bring up the ctrl-shift-esc list...

Comment: AHHHH - It turns out the domain was entered as `\\machinename` instead of `machinename` that throws off whatever parts of windows to do weird things.

Comment: Well, that fixed it for a day - it came back.   If I remove the hardware token / smart card on the system then it's fast, plug it back in, 4 minute wait.   How do I tell NLA to not try and use the smart card.   `advancedSettings.put_RedirectSmartCards(FALSE);` is already set.